# How do i select the ranges of date every year in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I have a database of 10 years and i would like to select the date that goes from 01-october-2015 to 01-jannuary-2016 and the date from 1-jannuary-2016 to 1-jun-2016 for every years. Here is my code:

```
WHERE date > to_date('01-OTT-15') AND date <= to_date('01-GEN-16')
WHERE date > to_date('01-GEN-16') AND date <= to_date('01-GIU-16')
WHERE date > to_date('01-GIU-16') AND date <= to_date('01-OTT-16')
WHERE date > to_date('01-OTT-16') AND date <= to_date('01-GEN-17')
WHERE date > to_date('01-GEN-17') AND date <= to_date('01-GIU-17')
```

and so on till today.

i was wondering if there is a more lean code or a loop to replicate this code.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products have their own functions, for example to_date().)

Comment: @jarlh Looks like Oracle to me.  I could be mistaken.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, most probably. However, I see it as a pedagogical exercise for OP to add the correct dbms tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its oracle

Comment: I'm a little lost.  Complete queries, sample data and desired results would really help.  How many result sets do you want?  Why not just include the date column in the result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to exclude the months of Jul, Aug, and Sep for all years (and maybe Jun, I can't tell from the question).

You can put this in a single `where` clause.  Using SQL Standard syntax (which also works in Oracle):

```
where extract(month from date) not in (7, 8, 9)
```

or more positively:

```
where extract(month from date) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12)
```